# How to compare values in a single dict with keys with multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I'm currently struggling with trying to make a program that takes text documents, in this case speeches and then compares them too each other.

I currently have a program that takes the files that user input and place the content into a dict with the key being the name of the file and the values the words of the speech, each word being its own element.

now the part where i am stuck is how to check the elements of each key against each other and then write the values that appear in all the keys to another file

all the answers i have been able to find in here have been about comparing two dicts to each other and not the content of a single dict

So far i have this

```
with open('compare_out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    for values in text_dict.values():
        fout.write(str(values))
```

I know there is no comparing here but i was trying to figure out how to just get to the right values and this seemed to do the trick so i'm guessing what i need is another loop of some kind to check the values

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and its desired output so we can understand the problem better?

Comment: Yes sorry i should have thought about that. the input is something like this

Fil_1.txt -> We the people
Fil_2.txt -> We people
Fil_3.txt -> The People

    `with open(fil_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8' ) as fin:
         text = fin.read().lower().split()
         for word in text:
             word = word.strip(string.punctuation) 
             word_list.append(word)
                
         text_dict.update({u2_input : set(word_list)})`

Dict = {Fil_name.txt : Words, words, words, Fil_name.txt : words, words}

My output should then be people because its a value in all keys